# I asked a question but now I can not find it

Tags: discussion, support, bug, asking-questions

I asked a question:

**Create Bash Alias That Accepts Commands**

but now I can not find it.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is: [Create bash alias that accepts arguments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1358909/create-bash-alias-that-accepts-arguments)

You can find your questions/answers by going into your [profile](https://askubuntu.com/users/1385532/ubunshitu).

Comment: I din't notice. However, the question is closed and remains unanswered. And that one other duplicate question, I do not understand at all.

Comment: Maybe it will solve your problem. But it did not help me with my example.

Comment: @ubunShitu The question is closed as a duplicate of another - how to add aliases.  Aliases accept arguments the same as the program that the alias would be calling.  That's why it's closed as a duplicate - have you checked that the duplicate that your question is closed as doesn't, in fact, help you?

Comment: In order to get a sufficiently different answer, you must ask a sufficiently different question. "*It did not help me*" does not make the question different.